# Can't get Code::Blocks to work on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, ide, osx-lion, codeblocks

I just installed Code::Blocks on my Macbook Air that runs OS X Lion and I can't get it to work.

At first, the problem was that I didn't have a C compiler installed, so I downloaded the developer tools, but now I'm encountering another problem: whenever I try to "Run and build" my test application, I get the following message: "Information: It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?".

I can then press "Yes", "No" or "Cancel". I obviously press "Yes", but that window keeps popping up over and over asking me the same question.

Also, when I try to quit Code::Blocks by using the Codeblocks menu and selecting "Quit and close all windows", it says the application has closed unexpectedly (and then I can either reopen, ignore or report).

I'm using version 10.05 of Code::Blocks.

I just want Code::Blocks to work like it does on my Linux system.

Comment: Hmm. Any particular reason to use Code::Blocks when you have Xcode installed?

Comment: @konrad No, I'm just not used to xcode, I'm just starting to learn objective-c with it. I'm a windows & linux user usually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had a similar problem. Mac OS X Lion developer tools doesn't install the command line tools to /usr/bin or any of the other typical system folders by default, which I believe Code::Blocks probably searches for programs such as make, g++, and other important tools. If it couldn't find make, than that might explain why the project wasn't built.

In order to properly install these, go to the preferences pane on XCode. From here select "Downloads" and then "Components." One of these items should be Command Line Tools. Just click "install and enter an apple ID."

You might have to register your apple ID as a developer. In order to do this go to:
http://developer.apple.com

Alternatively, you could use `ln` to link the developer commands to the /usr/local/bin directory, but you'd have to dig around in /Developer to find them.

Comment: I already did what you mentionned in xCode, so it's not working for me. I'll try the ln and tell you how it turned out. Thanks

Comment: It worked fine for me after installing the tools via XCode. I have the same hardware. Can you provide more details about the process you used to install it?

Comment: I downloaded Codeblocks for Mac on the official website, which came in a .dmg file. I opened it and there was a file named "Codeblocks", so I copied it in my applications folder and now I'm running it from the Launchpad. As for Xcode, it was already installed, so I ran it, went to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and clicked on "Install" besides "Command Line Tools". Now instead of the "Install" button, "Installed" is shown. That didn't work, so I also downloaded and installed the "Command line tools for Xcode - Late March 2012" from developers.apple.com to no avail.

Comment: Try deleting all of Code::Blocks' library files. They live in ~/Library/Application\ Support/codeblocks. If you delete that directory, it will reconfigure itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try this when I get back home. Since this is the first time I own a Mac, I don't really know how any of this work and I figured it might have had to do with the fact that it was configured with old / wrong settings that I couldn't change since it didn't change a thing when I reinstalled Code::Blocks for the second time.